# Non-ordered n-tuple?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

In many mathematics texts I've seen "ordered n-tuple" appear, and in such texts, there isn't any mention of just "n-tuple". So I'm wondering: are there really cases where one writes "n-tuple" and somehow it's not ordered? If not, I'm thinking the "ordered" in "ordered n-tuple" is really not necessary and can be shortened to just "n-tuple". Please let me know if there is significance is writing "ordered n-tuple" that I'm not seeing.

Comment: (8,3,2,8,3,1,4) was referred to as a 7-tuple in a lecture I had a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "ordered n-tuple" and "n-tuple" are synonym: See the wikipedia article [„tuple“](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) or [Wolfram's article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/n-Tuple.html).